# Multiple SCSS/LESS files or 1 big file

Tags: sass, less, file-structure

We are a small design / web shop. I have recently setup a new base repo using gulp and SASS/SCSS. When I setup our SCSS file structure I broke up our one massive LESS file we were using into a bunch of smaller SCSS files.

The new structure is like this

Inhouse

- typography
- tables
- buttons
- ...
- navigation
- sitewide
- single-pages

Vendor

- bootstrap
- fontawesome

Obviously this is a simplified layout.

This raised a discussion in house. Some of us preferred having 1 big LESS file and some of us (me) like having styles broken out into their own sheets. When I look online at other SCSS implementations I see them breaking their SCSS into multiple sheets, but perhaps that isn't best for custom / in house stylesheets.

I have not been able to convince anyone else that this is the correct method.

Can someone provide me with a good argument one way or the other? Is one large SCSS file easier to work with for in house / custom stuff or should we instead be using multiple files.

Comment: I think this is down to personal preference.  I prefer having them in smaller files simply because you can then compartmentalise the styling and find things easier.  If you know you have a specific style only on page X, or part Y, you can look in that one file rather than have to load a single monolith and search through that.  it (arguably) also makes merges easier to manage as it's only changes to small files rather than a lot of changes to one huge file.

Comment: We created something similar for our inhouse needs. We were guided by [bootstrap-scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) port method. Have everything broken into small pieces because you can always create one big file with simple @imports of those part (same as main bootstrap-scss file). Once you go down the "everything in one file" lane, it will be hard to break it down.

Answer (score 0):

Many modular sheets beat one big sheet every time. I haven't worked on many large client projects, but since I've switched to modular sheets it's so much better to hand over code or work with a team.

Bootstrap is the most popular css framework for a reason. I've adopted their philosophy and built a system similar to what you've described above, which I use to scaffold every project. Organization has never been better, and not having to scroll or cmd + f through a giant sheet has saved me several minutes per day.